# Time-consuming JavaRDD method take()

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, optimization

How to deal with time-consuming method provided by JavaRDD - take()

```
Instant startInit = Instant.now();
JavaRDD<Foo> fooJavaRDD = listOfFoo.parallize.map(new Foo()).sortBy(a -> a.sortRule(), true, NoPartitions);
Instant stopInit = Instant.now();

Instant startTake = Instant.now();
List<Foo> fooList = fooJavaRDD.take(1);
Instant stopTake = Instant.now();

System.out.println("Init: " + Duration.between(startInit, stopInit).toMillis());
System.out.println("Take: " + Duration.between(startTake, stopTake).toMillis());
```

Output I get (in millis):

```
Init: 417
Take: 1322
```

It's strange, that parallizing, map and sorting is not as time-consuming as take().

Maybe there is another way to take best result from map()?

Answer (score 2):

The `map()` actually doesn't get run until the `take()` is called in the code.  the Spark client is smart enough to not call `map()` until the results of `map()` are needed, and it doesn't see that happening until `take()` is called.  If you want the timing of `take()`, you can call `repartition()` or some other method that requires a shuffle in Spark. Then you will get the true time of `take()`.  Right now you are getting the time of both `map()` and `take()`.
It's not exactly intuitive and I have run into this many, many times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so how to deal with that? Foo() method called for List<Foo> takes 5-10 ms, JavaRDD<Foo> calling same method is, as you see, about 1500 ms.

Comment: Spark has a lot more overhead than just using a List.  For small inputs it will almost always be faster to do it outside of spark.  Spark becomes useful when the inputs grow very large and it's no longer practical to use a simple List to do the processing.

Comment: @cwiq I will echo what the previous comment said.  There is a lot of overhead in spark to start up all the workers and distribute the RDD to them.  The strength of spark is the distributed nature of it, to be able to run big work loads that can't be run on a single machine.

Comment: oh, one way to monitor performance of your spark operations is to look at the Spark History Server.